# How to utilize a while loop to animate and display a total

Tags: javascript, animation, while-loop

I'm trying to animate a total amount from input from the user. After the user inputs some numbers, the total animates from 0 to the total amount. I'm a bit confused after reading various books and thought StackOverflow would be the best way to practice my javaScript. Please tell me where I'm going wrong in my code.

The code is as follows:

```
<body>
<div>
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price">
    <br>
    <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity">
    <br>
    <label for="Amount">Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount">
</div>
<script>
var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
var amount = price * quantity;
var length;

function updateAmount(){
  while(amount = 0; amount <= amount.length; amount++){
    document.getElementById("amount").value;
}

setInterval(updateAmount, 10);
```

I'm a bit confused as you can see from my code. If you can steer me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and [easing equations](http://robertpenner.com/easing/). They will help a lot when working with animations.

I have created an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pswm6dx/3/) to show you requestAnimationFrame and easing equations in play.

HTML

```
<div>
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <input type="number" id="price" name="price">
    <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity">
    <label for="Amount">Amount:</label>
    <div id="amount"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var priceInput = document.querySelector("#price");
var quantityInput = document.querySelector("#quantity");
var amountDiv = document.querySelector("#amount");

priceInput.addEventListener('keyup', update);
quantityInput.addEventListener('keyup', update);


var aid = null; // request animation id
var startTime = 0;
var duration = 1000; // in milliseconds
var amount = 0;
var begin = 0;
var change = 0;

function update() {
    if (aid !== null) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(aid);
    }

    var price = parseFloat(priceInput.value || 0);
    var quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.value || 0);
    startTime = performance.now();
    begin = amount;
    change = (price * quantity) - begin;
    aid = requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

function step(ts) {
    aid = requestAnimationFrame(step);
    var elapsed = ts - startTime;
    if (elapsed < duration) {
        amount = easeOutQuad(elapsed, begin, change, duration);
        amountDiv.innerHTML = amount.toFixed(2);
    }
    else {
        cancelAnimationFrame(aid);
        amountDiv.innerHTML = (begin + change).toFixed(2);
    }
}

// t = time
// b = begin
// c = change
// d = duration
function easeOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * (t /= d) * (t - 2) + b;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. But, I want to use a while loop and reduce the amount of code with a while loop to simplify the code. Can this be done with a while loop. Just get the values for price and quantity, then multiply the two and animate the result ("amount")?

Comment: @Mark The while loop will iterate so fast you wont see the transition between the start and end value. So I understand why you used setInterval but they cannot be used together to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I would adjust the speed in setInterval and the loop will keep looping until the loop hits the amount total. Very simple.

Comment: The code works really good. It was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't expect to have to write all that code. I thought it would've been easier, but I guess that is the best way to approach the functionality I was looking for without using a plugin. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both a while loop (which will run synchronously until completion without delay) and a `setInterval`. You'll want to do away with the while loop part.

```
var displayedAmount = 0;
var updateInterval = setInterval(updateAmount, 10)

function updateAmount() {
  if (displayedAmount >= amount) {
     clearInterval(updateInterval);
     return;
  }

  displayedAmount++;
  document.getElementById("amount").value = displayedAmount;
}
```

A better approach that will perform better is to use animation frames. Decide the rate of change that you'd like, for example:

```
const changePerMillisecond = 0.001; // 1 dollar? per second
```

...or:

```
const changePerMillisecond = total / 5000; // Animation always takes 5 seconds
```

...and then you can use this animation frame loop:

```
const startTime = Date.now();
let displayedAmount = 0;
function animateValue() {
  const timeTranspired = Date.now() - startTime;
  displayedAmount = Math.min(value, timeTranspired * changePerMillisecond);
  document.getElementById("amount").value = displayedAmount.toFixed(2);

  if (displayedAmount < amount) 
    requestAnimationFrame(animateValue);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animateValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateAmount(){
  while(amount = 0; amount <= amount.length; amount++){
    document.getElementById("amount").value;
}
```

You forgot to assign the value of the amount element

```
document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
```

And if you want to see the amount actually changing, you will need to put a set interval when you update the input value. something like this:

```
function updateAmount(){
      while(amount = 0; amount <= amount.length; amount++){
        setInterval(function(){
           document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
        }, 300)

    }
```